# Why does while [ 0 ] go into infinite loop?

Tags: bash, shell, test

I see the same behaviour for below loop as the loop with `while [ 1 ]`. Why is that so?

```
while [ 0 ]; do
    echo "hello"
done
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Single square brackets in the shell is a synonym for `test` (either the separate command or the shell built-in), so `[ 0 ]` means the same thing as `test 0`. `test` is for doing comparisons and testing the attributes of files, as you can read about in its manpage. When it isn't given an expression that looks like a comparison, file test, or one of the other operations it can do, it will instead test if the argument is present and a non-empty string. Neither `0` or `1` are really appropriate inputs for test, and as non-empty strings test simply succeeds and your while loop loops forever.

You may want to try instead

```
while false; do
  echo "hello"
done
```

possibly replacing `false` with `true`. Or maybe what you want is to use `(( ))`:

```
while (( 0 )); do
  echo "hello"
done
```

Which will behave like most languages, where 0 means failure/false and 1 means success/true.

Comment: Re: "When it isn't given an expression that looks like a comparison, file test, or one of the other operations it can do, it simply succeeds": I don't think that's a good way to put it. After all, `[ ]` (with no argument) and `[ "" ]` (with a single empty argument) do *not* succeed.

Comment: As @ruakh explains, this statement is wrong: *When it isn't given an expression that looks like a comparison, file test, or one of the other operations it can do, it simply succeeds.* 

Any single argument to test (any single argument inside the square brackets) is considered TRUE if the argument is not an empty string, and both `0` and `1` are not empty strings.

New shell programmers often write `if [ 1=2 ]` instead of `if [ 1 = 2 ]` and wonder why the former is always true.  It is true because it is a single argument and is not an empty string.

Comment: Good points, I've made a correction.

Answer (score 10):

The value 0 here is not acting as a numeric constant, but as a character string. These tests are all equivalent in their effect of producing a successful termination status:

```
[ A ]
[ "XYZ" ]
[ 0 ]
```

these produce a failed termination status:

```
[ ]
[ "" ]
```

there is a non-blank argument, which evaluates to logical true. This allows you to do things like:

```
if [ $UNDER_NUCLEAR_ATTACK ] ; then
  launch-missiles -a $DRY_RUN  # $DRY_RUN set to "-n" during testing
fi
```

The variable `UNDER_NUCLEAR_ATTACK` is set to any non-blank value to indicate true, or is unset or empty to indicate false.

We can apply the `!` operator to reverse the logic:

```
[ ! a ]  # fails: a is nonblank so true; and not true is false.
[ ! ]    # succeeds: blank is false, not blank is true.
```

To evaluate a numeric condition, you have to use numeric test operators:

```
 while [ $A -gt $B ] ; do ...
```

If `A` and `B` contain strings that look like decimal integers, they are compared like numbers, and if `A` is greater than `B`, the loop executes.  So suppose that `UNDER_NUCLEAR_ATTACK` is not a string-type boolean that is blank or nonblank, but actually a numeric boolean that is either `0` (false) or some other value (true). In that case, we would write the test like this:

```
 if [ $UNDER_NUCLEAR_ATTACK -ne 0 ] ; then ...
```

Answer (score -1):

> An if/then construct tests whether the exit status of a list of
>   commands is 0 (since 0 means "success" by UNIX convention), and if so,
>   executes one or more commands.

In short, you're returning a test result of zero.

http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/testconstructs.html

Comment: Yes, but not for the reason you seem to think.  If `[` gets only one argument (excluding the `]`, of course) it exits with status zero if the argument is not empty, nonzero if it is. So, for example, `[ 1 ]` will also return an exit code of `0`.

Answer (score -1):

The 0 value is consider as a true for the while loop therefore the the condition for while loop is true and therefore it continuous to show the infinite loop.
The is true if we replace 0 with 1,as any integer we write between the condition it will return true